# How to get rid of port 8080 in URL?

Tags: iis, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex installation.

Apex is working fine through ip address : xx.yy.xx.yy:8080

I would like to access my application from my custom domain.

I installed IIS on my windows 10 server and I changed the DNS entries to route requests on my domain to the server ip address.

In my index.html file I added the following line :

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://xx.yy.xx.yy:8080">
```

The redirection woks but I have an ugly URL with the port number.

Does anyone know how to keep the domain name and get rid of the port number ?

(I can't change the port 8080 since it's the default port used by Apex)

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Reverse proxying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: You might also read through this series, notably parts 6 and 7, which discusses setting up a reverse proxy using Nginx (even if just to learn more about how things work): https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/09/best-and-cheapest-oracle-apex-hosting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another site and make sure it can be accessed via 8080.

1.Please install ARR&URLrewrite and ensure IIS manager->server node-> application request routing cache->server proxy settings->Enable proxy

2.Create a website with 80 port and make sure it can be accessed from http://xx.yy.xx.yy

3.Create URL rewrite rule like. You may need to modify this rule based on your requirement

```
        <rule name="rewrite">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="80" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://xx.yy.xx.yy:8080/{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
```

4.Please modify `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://xx.yy.xx.yy:8080">` to http://xx.yy.xx.yy">

Now when you access the web page.

Your page->redirect to http://xx.yy.xx.yy->URL reverse proxy rewrite to http://xx.yy.xx.yy:8080